# Questions about django-haystack when using Solr as a search engine

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

When django-haystack uses Solr as a search engine, can it only search accurately? How can I fuzzy search?

Comment: So what do you want to achieve with fuzzy search? Solr supports fuzzy (i.e. edit distance) search by using `~<distance>` after a term.

Comment: thank you very much!  i have known the answer